# How can I refresh the field in CSJS

Tags: xpages

How to refresh one field in csjs? the code is here:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" var="currentDetail" indexVar="detailIndex" value="#{LeaveBean.details}">
    <xp:inputText id="leavefrom" value="#{currentDetail.subfromtime}">
         <xp:eventHandler event="onblur" submit="false" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="repeat1">
                 <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
                      XSP.partialRefreshPost('#{id:view:_id1:repeat1:0:leavefrom}');
                      var detailIndex = document.getElementById("#{id:detailIndexText}").innerHTML;
                      myRPC.checkfromdate(detailIndex).addCallback(function(returnAlert){alert(returnAlert);});
                 ]]></xp:this.script>
      </xp:eventHandler>
   </xp:inputText>
</xp:repeat>
```

what I want to do is call ssjs from csjs as you can see, but the strange thing to me is the click thing didn't work immediately, for example, when I first open the page, and click the input field, and enter "1" in it, it should be popup alert just when i left the field, but nothing happend, then I click this field again, and enter "2", then I left the field, but I just got the alert "1" on the secreen...sorry for my poor expressions...

so my question is I should refresh the field just when I left the field immediately, but why the XSP.partialRefreshPost not working? I tried to refresh repeat1, not working either

update 2015/06/13:
At last, I found view.postScript....so....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious problem is the partialRefreshPost id won't work. You're combining `#{id:...}` which runs server-side to calculate the corresponding client-side ID. But the ID that you're passing is a client-side ID for the first row of the repeat. Even if that corresponded to a server-side component, you're trying to hard-code every row to map to a field in row 1 of the repeat ("repeat1:0").

Is there a reason for not using a normal partial refresh and using view.postScript in your SSJS to post CSJS back to the browser? You're triggering a partial refresh posting data back anyway. I'm not sure what the final line of your code is doing, but it seems like it's calling another server-side request to add a response. So the code seems to do two calls to the server, to trigger an alert. I don't know the design and what that subsequent rpc call is doing, but if it can be achieved in a single partial refresh, that would seem better.

Comment: thanks paul, at first, I choose to use the ssjs, and validation works fine, if user input wrong thing, the field will be cleand automatically, but I just can't show user why, so I want to use jquery to show notification, the question is jquery can't work in csjs...right? or I'm not right? anyway...I choose to use csjs to call ths ssjs, then show the notification...before post this question, I was thinking if there have any way to popup alert to user if they input wrong via ssjs...if the answer is yes, I will choose it...

Comment: If you include a Display Error control for the specific components or a generic Display Errors control in the refresh area, SSJS will show the user why the validation fails. Otherwise, it's registering the error, but there's no component available in the HTML being rendered back to the browser to explain why.